# PHP/MYSQL Query if not in second table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables.  I want to draw a sample of the first table except where the person in the first table is also in a second table.  Am having trouble doing this seemingly simple query.

table users

```
id|name
```

table catuser

```
id|userid|catid
```

I have tried

```
SELECT u.*,c.userid FROM `users` u
LEFT JOIN `catuser` c
ON (u.id = c.userid AND c.userid <> '197')
WHERE u.id = '1'
```

and variations to no avail.  Would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How abt. this:

```
SELECT u.*,c.userid 
FROM `users` u
LEFT JOIN `catuser` c
ON u.id = c.userid 
WHERE u.id = '1'
AND c.userid <> '197'
AND c.userid is null
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM catuser)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query only users that have one or more categories, you can use a `WHERE EXISTS` query:

```
SELECT u.* FROM `users` u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM catuser WHERE catuser.userid = u.id)
```

Another possibility is to do a left join, and check whether the join succeeded on checking on null:

```
SELECT u.*, c.* FROM `users` u
LEFT JOIN catuser c ON u.id = c.userid
WHERE c.id IS NOT NULL
```

If there is no corresponding row in catuser, all catuser fields will be null. By checking whether `c.id` is not null, you only include the rows with a category.

Note that the join may return a user multiple time, if he is in multiple categories.